# Spring Cloud app doesn't register correct port to Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've got a nice set of Spring Cloud -applications running but the actual applications register with wrong port to the DiscoveryServer.

I've got a Config-server, Eureka-server and a Zuul-server, which all talk to each other nicely and everything's shiny.

Then I added my actual app and everything wasn't shiny no more. My app runs on port `9001` and it works, but somehow it registers with `Eureka` on port `8080`.

I'm totally baffled as to what is going on.

gradle file: https://gist.github.com/2ee0b2b9a8490e6f25c0

application.yml: https://gist.github.com/f0e811d01eae83020bad

bootstrap.yml: https://gist.github.com/e947ac49a01ca1dfad0e

Comment: Are you running multiple applications on the same host? I don't see any server instanceId configuration, so the 8080 server is probably a different app.

Comment: @DaveSyer Yes, I'm running multiple applications on the same host. All have different ports, so that they don't clash. The thing is, that there is nothing running on `8080`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See docs on [how to make the Eureka instance ID unique](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_making_the_eureka_instance_id_unique). If you are running multiple servers on the same host, you need to configure an `instanceId` in the `eureka.intance.metadataMap`. Also, since you are using Eureka to discover the config server, all the eureka config should go in `bootstrap.yml`, including `server.port` so that the right metadata is sent by the client on startup.

Comment: Is this only for the clients?

Comment: Why "only"? It applies to all clients running on the same host.

Comment: I meant "Do I add that to the server too?"

Comment: But I added that to my `configserver` which correctly sends the new name, but my application doesn't register the correct name and port...

Comment: `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` defaults to 8080 (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java#L58) if you don't set it. Maybe you need to move your `server.port` to `bootstrap.yml`?

Comment: that worked, I'm just wondering why this worked and why it's ok for the `server.port` to be in `application.yml` for my `configserver` and `zuul-server`?

Comment: I think it's because you are using eureka to discover the config server. You have to have all the eureka pieces correct during bootstrap for that to work.

Comment: Care to edit your answer, so that I can accept it? :)